# How to tell if key is held down at click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to be able to tell if a user is holding down the "shift" key (or any key, really) when the user clicks something.

I'm able to tell if a user clicks something (by using the .click() method on the element in the directive) and also if a user presses a key, but I can't figure out how to tell if a user is holding down a key at click time in angular.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use the ngKeydown directive. calling it on your view like this.

```
ng-keydown="myFunct($event)"
```

myFunct could be like this.

```
$scope.myFunct = function(keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.which === 16) {// 16 == shift. I guess;
        $scope.shift_is_been_pressed = true;
    }
}
```

So. do the same with ngKeyup directive.

```
ng-keyup="myFunct($event)"

$scope.myFunct = function(keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent.which === 16) {// 16 == shift. I guess;
        $scope.shift_is_been_pressed = false;
    }
}
```

Now, you are able to use the shift_is_been_pressed to determine if shift is been pressed or not.